# Image resize without saving

Tags: php

I am trying to use PHP to grab a jpg image from a url and resize it and then display it in a webpage without having to save the new resized image.
My issue is that the image is not being shown to the page just a small blank square is being shown in my browser when I test the page with this script.

```
    <?php
       $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg("https://www.******.com/blog/post/b/l/health.jpg");
       $source_imagex = imagesx($source_image);
       $source_imagey = imagesy($source_image);
       $dest_imagex = 300;
       $dest_imagey = 200;
       $dest_image = imagecreatetruecolor($dest_imagex, $dest_imagey);
       imagecopyresampled($dest_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
       $dest_imagex, 
       $dest_imagey, $source_imagex, $source_imagey);
       header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
       imagejpeg($dest_image,NULL,80);
   ?>

<img src='<?php echo "$dest_image";?>'>
```

Comment: Why not just use CSS?

Comment: because i don't want the image to look stretched at all

Comment: the problem is in the img-tag. the source needs to be the php-script (called from another page obviously).

Comment: @user1739740 how would the image look stretched using CSS? Just set the width/height to the same ratio as the source image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all ensure that url of your image is correct. Lets assume that you have some `resize.php` for resizing your image.

**resize.php**

```
<?php
       $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSKTUtEWtyngG0EVhrOOZqJYhVPoFg5rzma6Xgn6Sy-RQCDCT950g");
       $source_imagex = imagesx($source_image);
       $source_imagey = imagesy($source_image);
       $dest_imagex = 100;
       $dest_imagey = 100;
       $dest_image = imagecreatetruecolor($dest_imagex, $dest_imagey);
       imagecopyresampled($dest_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
       $dest_imagex, 
       $dest_imagey, $source_imagex, $source_imagey);
       header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
       imagejpeg($dest_image,NULL,80);
   ?>
```

*here I just changed URL with an address I'm sure exist*

and then use it in some `html`:

```
<img src = 'resize.php' />
```

Answer (score 1):

You're dumping the image resource (`$dest_image`) into the source attribute of the image, which is no use.

If you want to print the image into the HTML response without having to save it to a file, you need to:

- First, get the output from `imagejpeg`, which are the raw bytes of the resulting image
- Then, encode those bytes into a Base64 string

Replacing the last line of your code with these should do the trick:

```
<?php
// [More code]
ob_start();
imagejpeg($dest_image, NULL, 80);
$image_bytes = ob_get_clean();
?>

<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($image_bytes); ?>">
```

Comment: only strange issue I am still having is now the images are blurry (instead of looking stretched.  The original images are really big in width and height and i am trying to resize it down to a much smaller thumbnail to show on a different page without the image looking distorted in any way.
The original image is 1110px wide by 400px height and I am trying to show the images on a separate page as a thumbnail at 210px width by 135px high.